MUI DataGrid getApplyQuickFilterFn applied only to first column
I am trying to apply same custom quick filter to multiple columns in MUI DataGrid. I followed the example in https://v6.mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/quick-filter/#custom-filtering-logic. Unfortunately, the filter is always applied to the first column only. Have you faced similar problem?
The GridCellParams are console.loged after typing anything into the search input. There one can see that only the first column is taken into account.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/epic-rubin-fhd5ys

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Column filters are checked sequentially. If the first column filter returns true, all following column filters are not checked.
